# How secure a user id with Golang Gorilla toolkit to be used with respect to sessions and secure cookies

Tags: security, session, go, gorilla

I have started to look at Gorilla Toolkit for Golang but I am having some difficulty in understanding of to use sessions or securecookies? I want to produce a secure user id which I can move between server and client so I initially thought I would use sessions but I cant see how to plug securecookie into it, without securecookie the sessions just perform base64 encoding?

I am sure I have missed something but to be honest I have done a lot of Googling but the examples I have seen are typically showing how to use sessions or securecookie but not sessions which are secure? Or do I just use cookies and forget sessions?

Again sorry if I have missed something simple but I would just appreciate a point in the right direction on which of the toolkit parts are to be used together a simple example would also be very appreciated.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Yes, don’t use securecookie directly (it’s a building block). sessions uses it automatically, and all sessions are thus authenticated (signed) by default.

Comment: Cheers elithrar its clicked now, I just did not see that in the documentation for Gorilla, thanks again.